# How to use currently logged in user varible in I18n locale file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, rails-i18n

I have a Rails app that I want to develop using both English and Japanese locales. Once the user logs in, the `:flash` displays in English "Logged in as " which is hard coded in to the sessions controller. In Japanese, the username would come first and the grammar would come after words (  としてログインされています), so I wanted to have different messages in the `en.yml` and `jp.yml` files.

The problem is that I can't get the logged in user's name to work in the yml files; instead of translating the variable to the currently logged in user, it merely displays the variable as text.

What am I doing wrong?

sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:info] = t(:logged_in_as) # points to translator in .yml file
      # flash[:info] = "logged in as #{@user.name}" works but English only 
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:danger] = t(:login_error) 
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end`
```

### jp.yml

```
ja:
  log_in_please: "ログインして下さい"
  logged_in_as: "%{user_name}  としてログインされています"
  login_error: "認証できません。入力された内容が正しくありません。"
  activerecord:
    models:
      users:
        name: user_name
```

EDIT: Here is the view for sessions:

```
<h1>Log in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The model is called 'users' and the user name field is called (drum roll) 'name'.

It works if I refer to `#{@user.name}` in the controller but can I use the user's name in the yml file?

I have read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html quite a few times but still can't find how to refer to the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

First, in the controller, you assign a variable that will be used in the I18n/locale file:

```
flash[:info] = t('logged_in_as', user: @user.name)
```

Here the `user:` can be assigned to a variable in the I18n file.

jp.yml:

```
logged_in_as: "%{user}としてログインされています。"
```

When the controller invokes the `t('logged_in_as')`, method, is passes `@user.name` to `user:` when the translation takes place. This works out well in the English yml file, too, since the order is different.

I found this buried in the guides file here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Hope someone else finds this useful (although since I didn't get a single comment, I doubt it).